# How to change page table entry to induce page fault in linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to estimate WSS (Working set size) of a process using a custom kernel and kernel module.

I first locate the task_struct of the process and iterate through all the vm areas from `mm_struct`. I was able to access all PTE's by walking the page table and check if page is present and estimate the RSS (Resident set size).

What I want to do now is change the PTE of VM areas such that it will cause page fault and my custom kernel will log the pagefaults in my required address range. From the page faults, I can estimate WSS. But when I try to change the `_PAGE_PRESENT` or `_PAGE_PROTNONE`, I get `swap_dup: Bad swap file entry` error and process crashes. Why isn't the actual page fault mechanism working when the flag is changed? What am I doing wrong?

This is my code snippet

```
    for (addr = vmstart->vm_start; addr < vmstart->vm_end; addr += PAGE_SIZE) {

            //Get PTE by walking page table
            pte_t *pte = walk_page_table(task->mm,addr),tmp_pte;

             //Only count present addresses:
            if(pte && (pte_val(*pte) & _PAGE_PRESENT)) {

                    tmp_pte = *pte;
                    set_pte(pte , pte_clear_flags(tmp_pte, _PAGE_PRESENT) ); 

                    printk(KERN_INFO "Flag changed at %lx , Name %s\n", addr,name);
                }
            }
            //unmap accessed page
            if(pte) pte_unmap(pte);
 }
```

`walk_page_table` returns pte of given virtual address. Please give suggessions.

The errors I get are

```
 swap_dup: Bad swap file entry
 BUG: Bad page map in process
```

Answer (score 0):

Swap page PTEs and in memory pages PTEs have completely different structure. Swap entries shows where pages are placed in the second storage, while normal PTEs describes physical page address + flags.
So, actually, the page fault mechanism is working, but where your page fault handler should search for swapped (no page present flag) page?

Comment: Ohh. Then from where can I get normal page table entries where it points to physical page?

Comment: they are already normal, but when you set NOT PRESENT flag for present pages you corrupt them. I'am not sure about what are you trying to accomplish, what is WSS?

Comment: In fact changing a flag to NOT PRESENT makes nothing, but only changing the flag. So your pages are still present in fact.

Comment: WSS is working set size. It is the number of pages the process use for a specific period of time (say 10 seconds). To calculate that, I am creating page fault and checking in the pagefault handler if process is accessing them during that time.

Comment: Anyway, by setting NOT PRESENT flag in this way you will corrupt PTE, not induce the page fault.